# Url link is not recognizable in html email

Tags: android, email, hyperlink, gmail

I'm trying to send an htlm email with a link in it. The url is "apk://teste.com".

```
<a href="apk://test.com"> Click here</a>
```

This is supposed to open an Android app if the user clicks on the link. The problem is when I receive the email in Gmail, the hyperlink doesn't appear. In hotmail the link appears in plain text.

Comment: How do you expect this to work for people who don't have this package? Crash Gmail with a `PackageManager.NameNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the html sanitization removes links which are not safe.

And using the direct `apk://` link will not work for people who don't have the app.

Instead, you can use an http link and let your application register the appropriate intent (for instance, matching http://www.example.com/). That way, users who have the app have the option to open the app when they follow the link ; and those who don't fall back on a web version.

Answer (score -1):

you should select the text you want then use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+K` (or `Cmd+K` on **Mac**) to insert a hyperlink into a text